# VB.net retrieve value from Confirmation Box

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

In layman's terms, basically what I want to do is:

I am exporting a dataset to a csv file, should the file exceed a predetermined size allow the user the option to email instead of downloading.
(So if the file > 10Mb Alert msg with option to email or to carry on downloading)

I.E "click yes to email, click no to download"

and

Retrieve the users selection

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Edited: Ok here is what I have tried

Script

```
            function confirmBox()
            {
                var hSize =  document.getElementById('<%= hFileSize.ClientID %>');
                if (hSize.value > 100)
                {
                    if (confirm(" Values is greater than 100. Continue?")==true)
                         return true;
                    else
                        return false;
                 }
            }
```

Asp button:

```
            <asp:Button ID="cmdExport" runat="server" Text="Export" OnClick="cmdExport_Click" OnClientClick="return confirmBox();"/>
```

But the problem is the message box is generated client side before the code behind has run to generate the CSV file and to get the File Size. So the message box needs to display only once I have generated the CSV and got the file size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by using a third party Telerik which I'm currently using.
By implementing Radtooltips/Radwindows.  http://www.telerik.com/

Answer (score 0):

**new answer based on the updated post**

In that case you need to send an ajax request to determine the file size after the parameters are submitted. if the value is greater than 10Mb show the popup. otherwise submit a full request back to the server to download the file.

from the message box, if the user clicks yes, send a full request back to the server to send an email with the attachment. if the user clicks no, send a full request to download the file.

Comment: I would even venture to *estimate* the file size just for performance (so you're not generating the whole *.csv file just to get the size), if the data lives in such a way where the data won't be inestimably random. Something even as simple as `if ((Rows * AverageRowSizeInBytes / 1024) > 10) ...`

Comment: @Jason Meckley, Ok I understand that part. let me edit and add what I have tried to attempt with the code

Comment: @Cory The csv has to be generated either way, it will either be downloaded or emailed.

Comment: @Jason Meckley I've edited my post hope that makes more sense as to what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: @Jason Meckley would you be able post an example for doing that in Ajax or point me in the right direction to look it up. Thanks

Comment: I use jquery for my scripting needs. there are built-in ajax calls. how you handle this on the server depends on if you are using webforms or an MVC framework.